# Is it possible to run Hadoop MR jobs using Google's Dataflow?

Tags: hadoop, avro, google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to run Hadoop MR jobs using Google's Dataflow service?

I have [several](http://sourceforge.net/p/contrail-bio/code/ci/master/tree/) Hadoop MR jobs which I'd like to be able to run on the Dataflow service. I'd like to be able to take advantage of the Dataflow service without having to completely rewrite my Hadoop jobs.

Comment: Hi there -- not sure I fully understood your suggestion. Can you explain what you have in mind here? Is it that:
- you'd like to use the Dataflow SDK to launch MR jobs?
- you'd like MapReduce code to be managed and executed by the Dataflow Service?
- you'd like to access data from HDFS in your Dataflow pipelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make migration easier, I think it should be possible to define a generic Dataflow Transform which could wrap Hadoop Mappers and Reducers so the code could be reused in Dataflow Pipelines.

Here is a very minimal implementation [AvroMRTransform](https://gist.github.com/jlewi/cf4b0ec3f4040c089b6c) that acts as a wrapper for AvroMapper and AvroReducer (i.e. it can only be used for inputs and outputs which are Avro data).

[AvroMRTransform](https://gist.github.com/jlewi/cf4b0ec3f4040c089b6c) works but there are almost certainly cases it doesn't handle. It also doesn't support a bunch of Hadoop features such as counters.

For these reasons, I wouldn't recommend this as anything other than a temporary stop gap measure (e.g. your application contains many MR jobs and you don't want to rewrite them all at once).

The Hadoop MR API strikes me as being very large so ultimately supporting every feature using Dataflow is probably going to be more work then just rewriting your application.